# Converting array of objects into pure array and access them

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a array of objects:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(Local\Model\PaymentModel)#259 (2) {
["_id":protected]=>
string(1) "1"
["_data":protected]=>
array(4) {
  ["payment_supplier"]=>
  string(15) "ACCESS MOBILITY"
  ["payment_ref"]=>
  string(6) "499778"
  ["payment_cost_rating"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["payment_amount"]=>
  string(7) "3694.60"
}
}
```

I've tried to convert it:

```
foreach($data['payments'] as $payment) {
  $array[] = (array) $payment;
}
```

As the result i become something like this:

```
array(2) {
["*_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["*_data"]=>
array(4) {
  ["payment_supplier"]=>
  string(15) "ACCESS MOBILITY"
  ["payment_ref"]=>
  string(6) "499778"
  ["payment_cost_rating"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["payment_amount"]=>
  string(7) "3694.60"
}
}
```

I have tried:

```
var_dump(array[0]['*_id']);
```

but I get an error 'Undefined index: *_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\tsh\v1\index.php on line 57'

My question is: how can I access this data?

Comment: try to check whether your object have methods to get the properties, maybe its available that way

Comment: var_dump(array['*_id']); . remove [0] position and try .

Comment: Nothing helps :(

Comment: `protected` translates to you are _not supposed_ to get the data this way. As @Ghost said, check whether this class provides methods to ask for this data.